# Facebook security algorithm: Locked out of my own account after resetting password

Tags: account-security, facebook, account-lockout

I created a secondary Facebook account months ago from Argentina. Now I logged back in, and noticed countless logins from RUSSIA and the account is clearly being used by some Russian dude.

I logged out from all devices, and changed the password, so far so good.

**But now I cannot login anymore from any device now because I'm asked to either**:

1. Login from a list of RUSSIAN devices I never used
2. Ask my fake RUSSIAN friends for help (I never added any friend)
3. Identify photos of fake RUSSIAN friends I never added.

[image]

**This occurs even after resetting the password via Email** (I do have access to the Email account), but **Facebook prioritizes the fact that someone has been using the account from Russia over the ownership of the Email account itself**. Yes this is actually happening, it's not a joke.

Could Mark Z. be more idiotic than this? They managed to use my compromised password to login from Russia and start adding friends, they happily deleted my verification phone number, **and now I cannot even login or delete the account after resetting my password successfully?**

Note the Russian hacker never changed the password nor the email. It just deleted my phone number and it has been using the account almost everyday, logging in from supposedly "*Samsung*" and "*Windows PC*" devices from a supposed city identified as Perm, Russia. Is there some way to make Facebook aware about this idiocy? I know the account is probably lost forever now, but at least I'd like to delete it permanently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question, is there some way to report the issue, is yes! You can report the incident here:

https://www.facebook.com/hacked

Comment: I'm still asked to "Confirm my identity" after that with the same process mentioned earlier.